# Need to duplicate the data using json with oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I have a json data like this :

```
"definition": [
        {
            "collectionId": "WORKS",
            "heading": "Subcategory",
            "autoLink": true,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "label": "Subcategory",
                    "aggFn": "NONE",
                    "datasetId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
                    "fieldName": "SUB_CAT",
                    "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-0"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Subcategory",
                    "aggFn": "NONE",
                    "datasetId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
                    "fieldName": "SUB_CAT",
                    "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-0"
                }
            ],
            "filterType": "MULTI_SELECT",
            "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-0",
            "linkedTabs": [
                "art-tab-0"
            ],
            "linkedWidgets": [
                "ART-TABLE-0"
            ],
            "operator": "IN",
            "required": false,
            "scope": "GLOBAL",
            "sortOrder": [],
            "validationType": "ANY_TEXT",
            "value": [
                "Brakes"
            ],
            "reciprocalType": "IN_OUT"
        },
        {
            "collectionId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
            "heading": "Category",
            "autoLink": true,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "label": "Category",
                    "aggFn": "NONE",
                    "datasetId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
                    "fieldName": "CAT",
                    "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-1"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Category",
                    "aggFn": "NONE",
                    "datasetId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
                    "fieldName": "CAT",
                    "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-1"
                }
            ],
            "filterType": "MULTI_SELECT",
            "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-1",
            "linkedTabs": [
                "art-tab-0"
            ],
            "linkedWidgets": [
                "ART-TABLE-0"
            ],
            "operator": "IN",
            "required": false,
            "scope": "GLOBAL",
            "sortOrder": [],
            "validationType": "ANY_TEXT",
            "value": [
                "Components"
            ],
            "reciprocalType": "IN_OUT"
        }
    ]
```

In this definition is the parent array. In this we have "value":[...] like this. I need to duplicate the data in the value in the name of label. The value data will not be same it will get differ. where and all value is there below that I need to duplicate the data in the name label. This is what my requirement.I need to achieve this in json using oracle. My oracle version is 19c

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 My Expectation output :

"dataFilterDefn": [
        {
            "collectionId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
            "heading": "Subcategory",
            "autoLink": true,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "label": "Subcategory",
                    "aggFn": "NONE",
                    "datasetId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
                    "fieldName": "SUB_CAT",
                    "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-0"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Subcategory",
                    "aggFn": "NONE",
                    "datasetId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
                    "fieldName": "SUB_CAT",
                    "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-0"
                }
            ],
            "filterType": "MULTI_SELECT",
            "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-0",
            "linkedTabs": [
                "art-tab-0"
            ],
            "linkedWidgets": [
                "ART-TABLE-0"
            ],
            "operator": "IN",
            "required": false,
            "scope": "GLOBAL",
            "sortOrder": [],
            "validationType": "ANY_TEXT",
            "value": [
                "Brakes"
            ],
            "label": [
                "Brakes"
            ],
            "reciprocalType": "IN_OUT"
        },
        {
            "collectionId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
            "heading": "Category",
            "autoLink": true,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "label": "Category",
                    "aggFn": "NONE",
                    "datasetId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
                    "fieldName": "CAT",
                    "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-1"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Category",
                    "aggFn": "NONE",
                    "datasetId": "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
                    "fieldName": "CAT",
                    "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-1"
                }
            ],
            "filterType": "MULTI_SELECT",
            "id": "ART-DATA-FILTER-1",
            "linkedTabs": [
                "art-tab-0"
            ],
            "linkedWidgets": [
                "ART-TABLE-0"
            ],
            "operator": "IN",
            "required": false,
            "scope": "GLOBAL",
            "sortOrder": [],
            "validationType": "ANY_TEXT",
            "value": [
                "Components"
            ],
            "label": [
                "Components"
            ],
            "reciprocalType": "IN_OUT"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Please simplify the example removing all not relevant parts. Show your effort and where you failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `$.definition` array and insert a new `label` attribute cloning the `value` attribute and then re-aggregate and merge back into the original object:

Either:

```sql
UPDATE table_name dst
SET json = (
  SELECT JSON_MERGEPATCH(
           t.json,
           j.updated_json
         )
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                    KEY   'definition'
                    VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                            JSON_TRANSFORM(
                              definition,
                              INSERT '$.label' = value
                            )
                          )
                  ) AS updated_json
           FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                    t.json,
                    '$.definition[*]'
                    COLUMNS(
                      definition JSON PATH '$',
                      value      JSON PATH '$.value'
                    )
                  )
         ) j
  WHERE  dst.ROWID = t.ROWID
)
```

Or:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT t.ROWID As rid,
         JSON_MERGEPATCH(
           t.json,
           j.updated_json
         ) AS updated_json
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                    KEY   'definition'
                    VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                            JSON_TRANSFORM(
                              definition,
                              INSERT '$.label' = value
                            )
                          )
                  ) AS updated_json
           FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                    t.json,
                    '$.definition[*]'
                    COLUMNS(
                      definition JSON PATH '$',
                      value      JSON PATH '$.value'
                    )
                  )
         ) j
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET dst.json = src.updated_json;
```

*(Note: this works in Oracle 21. I don't have an Oracle 19 instance to test it on.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=025837695c95dbb499016234aa5305b7)*